# How to click the icon without herf link with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I'm a newcomer of programming and I'm trying to crawl this [site](https://www.kcar.com/bc/search).
I'm sorry that the site is only for the Korean.

What i want to is move to next page in search using selenium (python).
At the other site, I can do it, finding the element with xpath and send '\n' keys.
but the site, the same method do not works.

The page num code like this
[page num code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEgBL.png).
it don`t have herf link and only li element.
how could i select the element and click it?

I try below code and .click() too.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[7]/div/ul/li[4]').send_keys('\n')
```

I expecting move to next page.

Answer (score 0):

To move to next page via pagination, you should do several actions:

1. Define selector of next page pagination button(it's `button.pageNext`)
2. Wait for next button presence
3. Scroll to element and make it appear in viewport
4. Wait for scroll to be finished to avoid temporary state, when element is not in viewport
5. Click on button

```py
def wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(element):
    initial_location = element.location
    previous_location = initial_location
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 1:
        current_location = element.location
        if current_location != previous_location:
            previous_location = current_location
            start_time = time.time()
        time.sleep(0.4)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)

url = "https://www.kcar.com/bc/search"
driver.get(url)

next_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.pageNext')))
actionChains.scroll_by_amount(next_button.location['x'], next_button.location['y'] - 100).perform()
wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(next_button)
next_button.click()
```